# Want a Button But Have to Use Input Where Type=File?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an <kbd>Import</kbd> button that I want to look like this:

[image]

The HTML for that looks like this:

```
<button on-read-file="importTasks(contents)" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="importTasks();">Import</button>
```

However, because I want the button to open a file, my research shows I need to use an input control and it looks like this:

[image]

Here is the HTML for it:

```
<input type="file" on-read-file="importTasks(contents)" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="importTasks();"></input>
```

I don't need the input box, and I don't need a button to say browse. I want the functionality of the second option, with the look of the first. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide the input and use a label whose "for" attribute matches the input's ID. Then simply style the label however you want.

```
<input type="file" id="abc" hidden>
<label for="abc">Import</label>
```

**Edit**

For completeness, here's the actual code that was used. Because the button was wrapped in a label, no extra styling was necessary.

```
<input id="hiddenImport" style="display:none" type="file" on-read-file="importTasks(contents)" ng-click="importTasks();"/>
<label for="hiddenImport"><button class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="loading">Import</button></label>
```

Comment: I never knew about the "for" attribute. Good to know. I don't want to have to worry about styling though. The accepted answer allows me to avoid that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: If you wrap a button in the above <label> you will get the exact same effect without having to style it yourself and without JS!

Comment: Oh, man, that's even better! I just tried it and it worked perfectly. This has to be the accepted answer now since it's the simplest. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes but you will need to use javascript. Make the file input hidden and then make the button click activate it like so

```
 <input id="files" type="file" style="display:none"/>
 <button id="upload" type="button"> </button>
 <script>
    $('#upload').click(function() {
      $('#files').click();
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: visibility:hidden is a css property. You can modify that part. But rest it is good.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by using `style="visibility:hidden"`. However, even though the control is invisible, it's still taking up space on the page and causing the rest of the controls to wrap to a new line. I like this answer because it's simple, but I have to get that input control to disappear.

Comment: @BobHorn `display: none` is like `visibility: hidden` except it will remove the item entirely, preventing it from taking up any space.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow That did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use CSS to make the input box transparent and add a button-like design over it like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="fileInput">
    <input type="file" on-read-file="importTasks(contents)" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="importTasks();"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fileInput {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: #CCC 2px solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:center;
}

.fileInput input {
    display: block !important;
    width: 80px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Link to jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/h40juz64/

---

**NOTE:** If you want the "INPUT" text over the button, you can either add it on a separate div and then use `css positioning` to move it over the Input box (which can get a bit tricky) OR you can just make an image with the "INPUT" text on it and then use it as a `background-image` for the button.

Comment: Appreciate the help. The other option was just too simple not to use.